# yfinance - isolating stock price

Tags: python, yfinance

G'day i was just curious how i could isolate the stock price using the yfinance module through python and then store that price as a variable, any help would be much appreciated.

```
import yfinance as yf

ticker = 'MSFT'
tickerData = yf.Ticker(ticker)

#get the historical prices for this ticker
tickerDf = tickerData.history(period='1d')

#see your data
tickerDf
```

This works but i end up with this and my various attempts to isolate and store the price (at close) has failed.
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2DuV.png)

thank you very much for any and all help

Comment: Not sure where you're getting stuck. Shouldn't tickerDf["Close"] give you the closing price?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to isolate both `Date` and `Close` columns in a separate dataframe 'close_df' you can use:

```
close_df=tickerDf[['Date','Close']]
close_df.set_index('Date')
```

and, if you want `Close` values in a list 'closed_values_list', use

```
closed_values_list= list(tickerDf['Close'])
```